# Going to each worksheet without going backwards

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a hard time trying to go through each worksheet in a workbook, get the name of a worksheet from another workbook and rename my main workbook worksheet. So, right now I have it so that the user can select a file they want to copy over to a new workbook with a different layout then the old one they have used. Then it gets the count of how many worksheets are in the old workbook and copies the worksheet in the new (Main)workbook. Afterwards it gets the name of each tab and renames the worksheet in the new (Main)workbook.

Mostly having trouble in this area of the code

```
For i = 1 To sheetcounts
            wbCopyTo.Activate
            wsCopyTo.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
            wbCopyTo.Worksheets(1).Activate
            'wbCopyFrom.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
            wbCopyFrom.ActiveSheet.Next.Activate

            wbCopyTo.ActiveSheet.Name = wbCopyFrom.ActiveSheet.Name
```

Here is the whole thing

```
 `Sub CpyOldTest()
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook
Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet
Dim cCounter As Integer
Dim rCounter As Integer

Dim sheetcounts As Integer
Dim i As Integer


Set wbCopyTo = ThisWorkbook
Set wsCopyTo = ActiveSheet

'On Error Resume Next



    '-------------------------------------------------------------
    'Open file with data to be copied
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*)," & _
    "*.xl*", 1, "Select Excel File", "Open", False)

    'If Cancel then Exit
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
        Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        'Get Count and Copy
        sheetcounts = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets.Count - 1

        For i = 1 To sheetcounts
            wbCopyTo.Activate
            wsCopyTo.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
            wbCopyTo.Worksheets(1).Activate
            'wbCopyFrom.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
            wbCopyFrom.ActiveSheet.Next.Activate

            wbCopyTo.ActiveSheet.Name = wbCopyFrom.ActiveSheet.Name

            'Copy Range
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            'Patient Information
     wsCopyFrom.Range("B2:B10").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("B2:B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Physician and Home Health care
     wsCopyFrom.Range("C12:C17").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("C12:C17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Diagnosis/TPN/Assessment Type
     wsCopyFrom.Range("B19:D21").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("B19:D21").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Calculated Needs
     wsCopyFrom.Range("E5").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("E5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     wsCopyFrom.Range("E7").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("E7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     wsCopyFrom.Range("E9:E10").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("E9:E10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     wsCopyFrom.Range("E12:E14").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("E12:E14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Intake/Lipids
     wsCopyFrom.Range("B23:C28").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("B23:C28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'TPN Components
     wsCopyFrom.Range("C30:C37").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("C30:C37").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'IBW adjustment
     wsCopyFrom.Range("F1").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Protein Needs
     'wsCopyFrom.Range("F12").Copy
     'wsCopyTo.Range("F12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Notes
     wsCopyFrom.Range("E19:F23").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("E19:F23").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Intake
     wsCopyFrom.Range("D23").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("D23").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Amino Acid
     wsCopyFrom.Range("D25").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("D25").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Total MLs
     wsCopyFrom.Range("D27").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("D27").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'KCal
     wsCopyFrom.Range("D29").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("D29").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'IV/Lipid/Fluid Bags
     wsCopyFrom.Range("E25:E27").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("E25:E27").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Access Device
     wsCopyFrom.Range("F29:F30").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("F29:F30").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Lab Frequency
     wsCopyFrom.Range("F33").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("F32").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Lab Data
     wsCopyFrom.Range("J2:P12").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("J2:P12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     wsCopyFrom.Range("J14:P32").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("J14:P32").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     wsCopyFrom.Range("G4:H32").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("G4:H32").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     wsCopyFrom.Range("I25:I32").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("I25:I32").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'TPN
     wsCopyFrom.Range("K34:P41").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("K37:P44").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     wsCopyFrom.Range("K43:P50").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("K46:P53").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Additives
     wsCopyFrom.Range("B39:F39").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("B42:F42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Subjective
     wsCopyFrom.Range("A41:F47").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("A44:F50").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Meds
     wsCopyFrom.Range("A50:F50").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("A53:F53").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Assessment Diagnosis
     wsCopyFrom.Range("A53:F56").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("A56:F59").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Nutrition Goals
     wsCopyFrom.Range("A59:F63").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("A62:F66").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Plan of Care
     wsCopyFrom.Range("A66:F72").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("A69:F75").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'------------------------------------------------------------------
            'List of Dietitians
     wsCopyFrom.Range("K62:P67").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("K65:P70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Dates
     wsCopyFrom.Range("C73:C74").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("C76:C77").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Education
     wsCopyFrom.Range("B75:H75").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("B78:H78").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Discussed
     wsCopyFrom.Range("B76:D76").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("B79:D79").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Dietitian
     wsCopyFrom.Range("A79:B80").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("A82:B82").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Evaluation
     wsCopyFrom.Range("D79:E79").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("D82:E82").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Pharmacy Information
     wsCopyFrom.Range("B86:D87").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("B89:D90").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     wsCopyFrom.Range("B88:B89").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("B91:B92").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            'Next due dates
     wsCopyFrom.Range("G86:G89").Copy
     wsCopyTo.Range("G89:G92").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Next i

    'Close file that was opened
    wbCopyFrom.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If

End Sub
```

I've tried many ways to get pass this and still no luck. Just wondering if I can get some help here. Sorry about the bad layout of the code just trying to get this done before I clean it up. Thank you.

Comment: You don't really state what the *actual problem* is. Hard to help without knowing specific problem.

Comment: As Scott said, we can only guess.Here's one guess: what if many of the worksheets you are copying have the same name?

Comment: @Scott Holtzman Hi, Sorry about that. I thought I did. When I run the code it needs to get the name of each sheet from the old workbook and make new sheets in the new workbook with those names. Also needs to copy the information that is in each worksheet to the new sheets in the new workbook.

Comment: @A.S.H None of the sheets will ever have the same name. Each of the worksheets are label by the date they have entered the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to activate the sheets.

Create a function to copy the Template and return a reference to the new worksheet.

`For each ws in Worksheets` is preferable over `For i = 1 to Worksheets.Count`

If you just want to copy the values of a contiguous range, it is better to do a direct assignment `Range("B1:B10").Value =`Range("A1:A10").VAlue`as opposed to`Range("A1:A10").Copy: `Range("B1:B10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

The `Worksheets` collection starts at index 1. This loop ships the last worksheet.

```
sheetcounts = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets.Count - 1 



Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

Sub CpyOldTest()
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook, wsTemplate As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

    '-------------------------------------------------------------
    'Open file with data to be copied
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*)," & _
                                        "*.xl*", 1, "Select Excel File", "Open", False)

    'If Cancel then Exit
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
        For Each ws In wbCopyFrom.Worksheets
            With getTemplateCopy
                .Name = ws.Name
                .Range("B2:B10").Value = ws.Range("B2:B10").Value      'Patient Information
                .Range("C12:C17").Value = ws.Range("C12:C17").Value    'Physician and Home Health care
                .Range("B19:D21").Value = ws.Range("B19:D21").Value    'Diagnosis/TPN/Assessment Type
                '-------------------------------------------------------------------
                'Calculated Needs
                .Range("E5").Value = ws.Range("E5").Value
                .Range("E7").Value = ws.Range("E7").Value
                .Range("E9:E10").Value = ws.Range("E9:E10").Value
                .Range("E12:E14").Value = ws.Range("E12:E14").Value
                '-------------------------------------------------------------------
                .Range("B23:C28").Value = ws.Range("B23:C28").Value    'Intake/Lipids
                .Range("C30:C37").Value = ws.Range("C30:C37").Value  'TPN Components
                .Range("F1").Value = ws.Range("F1").Value    'IBW adjustment
                '.Range("F12").value = ws.Range ("F12").value 'Protein Needs
                .Range("E19:F23").Value = ws.Range("E19:F23").Value  'Notes
                '-------------------------------------------------------------------
                .Range("D23").Value = ws.Range("D23").Value    'Intake
                .Range("D25").Value = ws.Range("D25").Value    'Amino Acid
                .Range("D27").Value = ws.Range("D27").Value    'Total MLs
                .Range("D29").Value = ws.Range("D29").Value    'KCal
                .Range("E25:E27").Value = ws.Range("E25:E27").Value    'IV/Lipid/Fluid Bags
                .Range("F29:F30").Value = ws.Range("F29:F30").Value    'Access Device
                .Range("F32").Value = ws.Range("F33").Value    'Lab Frequency
                '-------------------------------------------------------------------
                'Lab Data
                .Range("J2:P12").Value = ws.Range("J2:P12").Value
                .Range("J14:P32").Value = ws.Range("J14:P32").Value
                .Range("G4:H32").Value = ws.Range("G4:H32").Value
                .Range("I25:I32").Value = ws.Range("I25:I32").Value
                .Range("K37:P44").Value = ws.Range("K34:P41").Value    'TPN
                .Range("K46:P53").Value = ws.Range("K43:P50").Value
                '------------------------------------------------------------------
                .Range("B42:F42").Value = ws.Range("B39:F39").Value    'Additives
                .Range("A44:F50").Value = ws.Range("A41:F47").Value    'Subjective
                .Range("A53:F53").Value = ws.Range("A50:F50").Value    'Meds
                .Range("A56:F59").Value = ws.Range("A53:F56").Value    'Assessment Diagnosis
                .Range("A62:F66").Value = ws.Range("A59:F63").Value  'Nutrition Goals
                .Range("A69:F75").Value = ws.Range("A66:F72").Value    'Plan of Care
                '------------------------------------------------------------------
                .Range("K65:P70").Value = ws.Range("K62:P67").Value    'List of Dietitians
                .Range("C76:C77").Value = ws.Range("C73:C74").Value    'Dates
                .Range("B78:H78").Value = ws.Range("B75:H75").Value    'Education
                .Range("B79:D79").Value = ws.Range("B76:D76").Value    'Discussed
                .Range("A82:B82").Value = ws.Range("A79:B80").Value    'Dietitian
                .Range("D82:E82").Value = ws.Range("D79:E79").Value    'Evaluation
                '------------------------------------------------------------------
                'Pharmacy Information
                .Range("B89:D90").Value = ws.Range("B86:D87").Value
                .Range("B91:B92").Value = ws.Range("B88:B89").Value
                '------------------------------------------------------------------
                .Range("G89:G92").Value = ws.Range("G86:G89").Value    'Next due dates
            End With
        Next

        'Close file that was opened
        wbCopyFrom.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

End Sub

Function getTemplateCopy() As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
    ws.Copy After:=ws
    Set getTemplateCopy = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. I was thinking about splitting the workload with `i = 1 To Worksheets.count` and `For ws in wbCopyFrom`.